# Confusion around bracketed objects [{"a":"b"}] and non-bracketed objects {"a":"b"} in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, object, brackets

I've had an AJAX result that get's `json_encode($result);` in PHP before being returned.

Originally the data returned looked like this:

```
[{"ID":"4066","post_title":"TATTOO SLEEVES"}]
```

**Note it has [ ] brackets!!**
Then I would parseJSON the data and work with it.

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

However, I need to return an extra value, so in the AJAX hook before returning I added:

```
$sql_search["sql_search_count"] = $sql_search_count;
```

Now suddenly my data gets returned like this:

```
{"0":{"ID":"4066","post_title":"TATTOO SLEEVES"},"sql_search_count":"1"}
```

**No more [ ] brackets!**
I'm trying to split this data; getting the "0" string part, and pushing it through a `$.parseJSON(data);` just like before. But I cannot seem to find out how.

Why are there sometimes [ ] brackets and sometimes not?

**How do I get the "0" string in a new variable with [ ] around it?**

I tried the following:

`$sql_search[0]["sql_search_count"] = $sql_search_count;` 
but that gives me an error...

**If I change it to** `$sql_search[0]->sql_search_count = $sql_search_count;` **it works.**
But it is not not on the top level, it becomes a child of the first result like this:
`[{"ID":"4066","post_title":"TATTOO SLEEVES","sql_search_count","1"}]`

Comment: "I'm trying to split this data; getting the "0" string part" - WRONG! The whole thing is a JSON, so parse it as a whole.

Comment: if you need the count of the elements returned you can easly get that value with `$.parseJSON(data).length` without adding a new param.

Comment: You will have "1" strings and "2" strings as well if there are more entries in the array. Don't just set the sql_search_count directly on the array. Wrap everything in some object, like `{ sql_search_count : 1 , results: [ /* your old Array*/ ] }`

Comment: How to do that Thilo?

Comment: You should create a new object and then add it to the original with array_push then you will get an array with two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

`$sql_search[0]["sql_search_count"] = $sql_search_count;`

in your PHP code and it'll start working as before. The reason why the brackets are missing is that

`$sql_search["sql_search_count"] = $sql_search_count;`

will ask PHP to include a key called `sql_search_count` into `$sql_search` variable. Since its an array, it directly cant. It converts it into the format you're seeing now.

Comment: Yea, it basically converts an array (note that [] brackets which are used for arrays) to an object (which uses {} brackets in declaration).

Comment: Well, that won't work too well if the array has no elements (I am assuming it can have been 0 and many).

Comment: Actually @shashanka-n , `$sql_search[0]["sql_search_count"] = $sql_search_count;` gives me an error...  But if I change it to `$sql_search[0]->sql_search_count = $sql_search_count;` it would work. But it is not not on the top level, but it becomes a child of the first result like this: `[{"ID":"4066","post_title":"TATTOO SLEEVES","sql_search_count","1"}]`. I've updated the question.

Comment: @shashanka n thanks for your help. Sorry I marked it correct many years later. Your upvote on my question is much appreciated!! : D